# Angularfire2 and ionic 2 - mapping all UIDs from Firebase except currentuser's

Tags: firebase, ionic2, angularfire2

I am trying to develop a system with 2 different views, being the first "My books" and the second "Other people books"

for the first view i have this working fine

```
this.mybooks = angFire.database.list('/user-books', {
  query: {
    orderByChild: 'uid',
    equalTo: firebase.auth().currentUser.uid
  }
});
```

but i dont know how to create something that would work as a "notEqualTo" function to exclude all books owned by the current user.

this is my  Firebase structure for reference

```
{
  "user-books" : {
    "-KfJ9CprqgOWN9Ud_CvG" : {
      "author" : "sdasd",
      "city" : "asd",
      "description" : "asdasd",
      "title" : "asda",
      "uid" : "bazvEYBL6sgfa6HSmqvtAlX3f0l2"
    },
    "-KfJARoEU_FDW80hg4ws" : {
      "author" : "in",
      "city" : "chaaat",
      "description" : "the",
      "title" : "Pogchamps",
      "uid" : "tzROGF1Tk4NcobrTE70ZKQzoKom1"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The firebase data structure you are currently using, which nests books inside user objects, is probably not the best for your exact use. The firebase docs have a section devoted to that right [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/structure-data). One of the subsections is titled "avoid nesting data".

A better structure would normalise books and put them in a separate collection/table. For storing the users books, you can still have the books array, but in it just store the keys (ids) from the books table.

Listing other people's books, then, just becomes listing all the books from the books table and filtering out the current user's books.

Note that, especially in data stores like firebase, the optimal data structure entirely depends on how you use the data. Storing the user-book link inside the user object is a good approach, only if your app focuses on listing a user's books. If, on the contrary, the focus would be to list users for a book, it would be better to store arrays of user ids inside the books collection.

Comment: thanks for the tips, i now moved "books" to first level and added a "uid" field to it, so i can filter the books on "My books" screen but i still dont know how to exclude data, something like a "notEqualTo()" function

Comment: Note that the uid field is not really necessary. You can just use the $key that firebase assigns to the object. Furthermore, for filtering you can use a [angular 2 pipe](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/pipes.html) in the *ngFor or you can use one of javascripts array functions like [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)